# Continuous threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, infinite-loop

I want to make an application that listens for some kind of input constantly, without pauses (delaying the read, misses the message) and writing the message to a database (which in my case takes 60ms).

My idea is to have the listening function threaded (or not) in a `while(1)` loop, which adds to an array/vector of structs (in the below code it is a single variable `int newValues`) and then check if there is a message available and spawn a thread to deal with it. I also tried to spawn a thread from the listening function for every received message (which is the preferable method, but I don't know if I can spawn infinite threads) but both times the program terminates with: `pure virtual method called`. I found out that it means that a member of a destructed object is called, but this doesn't help me understand why the below code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

int newValues;  //if this is under 20 then it should be displayed

void listen();
void available();

int main() {
    while (1) {
        //constantly listen
        //this works for a little longer if is called without a thread
        thread lis(listen);
        lis.detach();

        if (newValues < 20) {  //if needed display it
            thread ava(available);  //without disrupting the listening
            ava.detach();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void listen() {
    newValues = rand() % 100;
}

void available() {
    cout << newValues << endl;
}
```

The output from *gdb* is:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19329)]
[New Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19330)]
[Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19329) exited]
[Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19330) exited]
[New Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19331)]
[Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19331) exited]
[New Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19332)]
[Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19332) exited]
[New Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19333)]
15
[New Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19334)]
[Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19334) exited]
[New Thread 0x75bb2450 (LWP 19335)]
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
[New Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19336)]
[New Thread 0x753b2450 (LWP 19337)]
pure virtual method called
terminate called recursively
[Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19336) exited]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x75bb2450 (LWP 19335)]
0x76bf3f50 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y

Starting program: /home/pi/smart_home/mw_0.1/RPi/nRF24/thread
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19341)]
[New Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19342)]
[Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19341) exited]
[Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19342) exited]
[New Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19343)]
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
[New Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19344)]
[New Thread 0x75bb2450 (LWP 19345)]
[Thread 0x763b2450 (LWP 19344) exited]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x76bb2450 (LWP 19343)]
0x76bf3f50 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

---

The output from the actual application:

```
[New Thread 0x75bb2450 (LWP 19686)]
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception  // <- difference
[New Thread 0x753b2450 (LWP 19687)]
[New Thread 0x74bb2450 (LWP 19688)]
pure virtual method called
[Thread 0x753b2450 (LWP 19687) exited]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x75bb2450 (LWP 19686)]
0x76bf3f50 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

But the idea is the same and the code won't work on another machine.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Your are not spawning one thread which listens infinite, you are spawning "infinite" many threads in your while loop which wirte something in newValue. You should make yourself more familiar with concurrency. For your problem you need a observer pattern.  You may have a look at [Boost Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/signals2.html)

Comment: Good point about the infinite threads, but why is it not working when I call the listening function without a thread, it returns the same output, but after longer execution. I will have a look at Boost Signals but isn't the above code close to working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your comment, you have a data race on `newValues` with infinite threads, which is undefined behavior. You need some kind of synchronization (a mutex or an atomic data type).